# Split string into array in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am looking for a way to split a string in bash over a delimiter string, and place the parts in an array.

Simple case:

```
#!/bin/bash
b="aaaaa/bbbbb/ddd/ffffff"
echo "simple string: $b"

IFS='/' b_split=($b)
echo ;
echo "split"
for i in ${b_split[@]}
do
    echo "------ new part ------"
    echo "$i"
done
```

Gives output

```
simple string: aaaaa/bbbbb/ddd/ffffff

split
------ new part ------
aaaaa
------ new part ------
bbbbb
------ new part ------
ddd
------ new part ------
ffffff
```

More complex case:

```
#!/bin/bash
c=$(echo "AA=A"; echo "B=BB"; echo "======="; echo "C==CC"; echo "DD=D"; echo "======="; echo "EEE"; echo "FF";)
echo "more complex string"
echo "$c";
echo ;
echo "split";

IFS='=======' c_split=($c) ;#    <----    LINE TO BE CHANGED 

for i in ${c_split[@]}
do
    echo "------ new part ------"
    echo "$i"
done
```

Gives output:

```
more complex string
AA=A
B=BB
=======
C==CC
DD=D
=======
EEE
FF

split
------ new part ------
AA
------ new part ------
A
B
------ new part ------
BB

------ new part ------

------ new part ------

------ new part ------

------ new part ------

------ new part ------

------ new part ------

------ new part ------

C
------ new part ------

------ new part ------
CC
DD
------ new part ------
D

------ new part ------

------ new part ------

------ new part ------

------ new part ------

------ new part ------

------ new part ------

------ new part ------

EEE
FF
```

I would like the second output to be like

```
------ new part ------
AA=A
B=BB
------ new part ------
C==CC
DD=D
------ new part ------
EEE
FF
```

I.e. to **split** the string on a **sequence of characters**, instead of one. How can I do this?

I am looking for an answer that would only modify this line in the second script:

```
IFS='=======' c_split=($c) ;#    <----    LINE TO BE CHANGED
```

Comment: If what you are looking for is to tweak IFS to use more than one character as a delimiter, it is not possible. please check this thread for more info: [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7904/can-ifs-internal-field-separator-function-as-a-single-seperator-for-multiple-c)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Introduction

At bottom of this, you will find a function to transform *string* to an *array* with following syntax:

```
ssplit "<string>" "<array name>" "<delimiter string>"
```

For this:

```
ssplit "$c" c_split $'\n=======\n'
declare -p c_split 
declare -a c_split=([0]=$'AA=A\nB=BB' [1]=$'C==CC\nDD=D' [2]=$'EEE\nFF')
```

#### `IFS` disambiguation

`IFS` mean *Input Field Separators*, as *`list of characters that could be used as separators`*.

By default, this is set to      `\t\n`, meaning that any number (greater than zero) of *space*, *tabulation* **and/or** *newline* could be **one** *`separator`*.

So with the string: `$'    blah  foo=bar \nbaz  '`

```
 read -a c_split <<<"    blah  foo=bar 
 baz  "
 declare -p c_split 
 declare -a c_split=([0]="blah" [1]="foo=bar")
```

Leading and trailing *separators* would be ignored and this string will contain only 3
parts: `blah`, `foo=bar` and `baz`.

But except for *spaces*, IFS consider **each** separator for itself:

```
IFS=Z read a b c d e f <<<ZaZZbZcZZdZeZf
declare -p a b c d e f
declare -- a=""
declare -- b="a"
declare -- c=""
declare -- d="b"
declare -- e="c"
declare -- f="ZdZeZf"
```

Splitting a string using `IFS` is possible if you know a valid field separator not used in your string, so you could **replace** your *pattern* by this character (by using `${var//<pattern>/<separator>}` syntax):

```
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS='§'
c=$'AA=A\nB=BB\n=======\nC==CC\nDD=D\n=======\nEEE\nFF'
c_split=(${c//=======/§})
IFS="$OIFS"
printf -- "------ new part ------\n%s\n" "${c_split[@]}"

------ new part ------
AA=A
B=BB

------ new part ------

C==CC
DD=D

------ new part ------

EEE
FF
```

But this work only while string do not contain any `§`.

You could use another character, like `IFS=$'\026';c_split=(${c//=======/$'\026'})` but anyway this may involve furter bugs.

You could browse character maps for finding one who's not in your string:

```
myIfs=""
for i in {1..255};do
    printf -v char "$(printf "\\\%03o" $i)"
        [ "$c" == "${c#*$char}" ] && myIfs="$char" && break
  done
if ! [ "$myIFS" ] ;then
    echo no split char found, could not do the job, sorry.
    exit 1
  fi
```

but I find this solution a little overkill.

#### Splitting on spaces (or without modifying IFS)

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), we could use this bashism:

```
b="aaaaa/bbbbb/ddd/ffffff"
b_split=(${b//// })
```

In fact, this syntaxe `${varname//` will initiate a translation (delimited by `/`) replacing all occurences of `/` by a space  , **before** assigning it to an array `b_split`.

Of course, this still use `IFS` and split array on spaces.

This is not the best way, but could work with specific cases.

You could even drop unwanted spaces before splitting:

```
b='12 34 / 1 3 5 7 / ab'
b1=${b// }
b_split=(${b1//// })
printf "<%s>, " "${b_split[@]}" ;echo
<12>, <34>, <1>, <3>, <5>, <7>, <ab>,
```

or exchange thems...

```
b1=${b// /§}
b_split=(${b1//// })
printf "<%s>, " "${b_split[@]//§/ }" ;echo
<12 34 >, < 1 3 5 7 >, < ab>,
```

#### Splitting line on *`delimiter strings`*:

So you have to *not* use `IFS` for your meaning, but [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) do have nice features:

```
#!/bin/bash

c=$'AA=A\nB=BB\n=======\nC==CC\nDD=D\n=======\nEEE\nFF'
echo "more complex string"
echo "$c";
echo ;
echo "split";

mySep='======='
while [ "$c" != "${c#*$mySep}" ];do
    echo "------ new part ------"
    echo "${c%%$mySep*}"
    c="${c#*$mySep}"
  done
echo "------ last part ------"
echo "$c"
```

Let see:

```
more complex string
AA=A
B=BB
=======
C==CC
DD=D
=======
EEE
FF

split
------ new part ------
AA=A
B=BB

------ new part ------

C==CC
DD=D

------ last part ------

EEE
FF
```

#### About Leading *newline*

Leading and trailing newlines are not deleted in previous samples. For this, you could simply:

```
mySep=$'\n=======\n'
```

instead of `=======`.

Or you could rewrite split loop for keeping explicitely this out:

```
mySep=$'======='
while [ "$c" != "${c#*$mySep}" ];do
    echo "------ new part ------"
    part="${c%%$mySep*}"
    part="${part##$'\n'}"
    echo "${part%%$'\n'}"
    c="${c#*$mySep}"
  done
echo "------ last part ------"
c=${c##$'\n'}
echo "${c%%$'\n'}"
```

Any case, this match what SO question asked for (: and his sample :)

```
------ new part ------
AA=A
B=BB
------ new part ------
C==CC
DD=D
------ last part ------
EEE
FF
```

#### Finaly creating an *`array`*.

```
#!/bin/bash
c=$'AA=A\nB=BB\n=======\nC==CC\nDD=D\n=======\nEEE\nFF'
echo "more complex string"
echo "$c";
echo ;
echo "split";

mySep=$'======='
export -a c_split
while [ "$c" != "${c#*$mySep}" ];do
    part="${c%%$mySep*}"
    part="${part##$'\n'}"
    c_split+=("${part%%$'\n'}")
    c="${c#*$mySep}"
  done
c=${c##$'\n'}
c_split+=("${c%%$'\n'}")

for i in "${c_split[@]}"
do
    echo "------ new part ------"
    echo "$i"
done
```

Do this finely:

```
more complex string
AA=A
B=BB
=======
C==CC
DD=D
=======
EEE
FF

split
------ new part ------
AA=A
B=BB
------ new part ------
C==CC
DD=D
------ new part ------
EEE
FF
```

#### Some explanations:

- `export -a var` to define `var` as an array and share them in childs
- `${variablename%string*}`, `${variablename%%string*}` result in the left part of *variablename*, upto but without *string*. One `%` mean *last occurence of string* and `%%` for *all occurences*. Full *variablename* is returned is *string* not found.
- `${variablename#*string}`, do same in reverse way: return last part of *variablename* from but without *string*. One `#` mean *first occurence* and two `##` man *all occurences*.

Nota in replacement, character `*` is a *joker* mean any number of any character.

The command `echo "${c%%$'\n'}"` would echo variable **c** but without any number of newline at end of string.

So if *variable* contain `Hello WorldZorGluBHello youZorGluBI'm happy`,

```
variable="Hello WorldZorGluBHello youZorGluBI'm happy"

$ echo ${variable#*ZorGluB}
Hello youZorGlubI'm happy

$ echo ${variable##*ZorGluB}
I'm happy

$ echo ${variable%ZorGluB*}
Hello WorldZorGluBHello you

$ echo ${variable%%ZorGluB*}
Hello World

$ echo ${variable%%ZorGluB}
Hello WorldZorGluBHello youZorGluBI'm happy

$ echo ${variable%happy}
Hello WorldZorGluBHello youZorGluBI'm

$ echo ${variable##* }
happy
```

All this is explained in the manpage:

```
$ man -Len -Pless\ +/##word bash

$ man -Len -Pless\ +/%%word bash

$ man -Len -Pless\ +/^\\\ *export\\\ .*word bash
```

#### Step by step, the splitting loop:

The separator:

```
mySep=$'======='
```

Declaring `c_split` as an *array* (and could be shared with childs)

```
export -a c_split
```

While variable **c** do contain at least one occurence of `mySep`

```
while [ "$c" != "${c#*$mySep}" ];do
```

Trunc **c** from first `mySep` to end of string and assign to `part`.

```
    part="${c%%$mySep*}"
```

Remove leading newlines

```
    part="${part##$'\n'}"
```

Remove trailing newlines and add result as a new array element to `c_split`.

```
    c_split+=("${part%%$'\n'}")
```

Reassing **c** whith the rest of string when left upto `mySep` is removed

```
    c="${c#*$mySep}"
```

Done ;-)

```
done
```

Remove leading newlines

```
c=${c##$'\n'}
```

Remove trailing newlines and add result as a new array element to `c_split`.

```
c_split+=("${c%%$'\n'}")
```

#### Into a function:

```
ssplit() {
    local string="$1" array=${2:-ssplited_array} delim="${3:- }" pos=0
    while [ "$string" != "${string#*$delim}" ];do
        printf -v $array[pos++] "%s" "${string%%$delim*}"
        string="${string#*$delim}"
      done
    printf -v $array[pos] "%s" "$string"
}
```

Usage:

```
ssplit "<quoted string>" [array name] [delimiter string]
```

where *array name* is `$splitted_array` by default and *delimiter* is one single space.

You could use:

```
c=$'AA=A\nB=BB\n=======\nC==CC\nDD=D\n=======\nEEE\nFF'
ssplit "$c" c_split $'\n=======\n'
printf -- "--- part ----\n%s\n" "${c_split[@]}"
--- part ----
AA=A
B=BB
--- part ----
C==CC
DD=D
--- part ----
EEE
FF
```

Comment: Thanks for the excelent answer and the detailed explenation. Well done! You dedinitely deserve more upvotes, but I can only give one... :)

Comment: I'm trying to use this solution, but my separator is a long line with asterisks (*). I have tried changing the separator for a regular expression, but that doesn't work. Is it possible to do something like: `mySep="/\*{50,}/"`?

Comment: Also my string is loaded from a file (multiline): `c=\`cat /home/pi/test.txt\`` if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

do it with awk:

```
 awk -vRS='\n=*\n'  '{print "----- new part -----";print}' <<< $c
```

output:

```
kent$  awk -vRS='\n=*\n'  '{print "----- new part -----";print}' <<< $c
----- new part -----
AA=A
B=BB
----- new part -----
C==CC
DD=D
----- new part -----
EEE
FF
```

Comment: Thanx and +1 for answering. But I can't mark as accepted because (correct me if I am wrong) you process each part in awk but you can't return each part as a separate element in an array. Could you modify?

Comment: @user000001 is right saying that there is only a filter not a splitting method: `sed $'bb;:a;i----- new part -----\n;1p;d;:b;1ba;/^====*$/ba;'` do the same...

Answer (score 1):

Following script tested in bash:

```
kent@7pLaptop:/tmp/test$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.42(2)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
```

the script: (named `t.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash

c=$(echo "AA=A"; echo "B=BB"; echo "======="; echo "C==CC"; echo "DD=D"; echo "======="; echo "EEE"; echo "FF";)
echo "more complex string"
echo "$c"
echo "split now"

c_split=($(echo "$c"|awk -vRS="\n=*\n"  '{gsub(/\n/,"\\n");printf $0" "}'))

for i in ${c_split[@]}
do
    echo "---- new part ----"
    echo -e "$i" 
done
```

output:

```
kent@7pLaptop:/tmp/test$ ./t.sh 
more complex string
AA=A
B=BB
=======
C==CC
DD=D
=======
EEE
FF
split now
---- new part ----
AA=A
B=BB
---- new part ----
C==CC
DD=D
---- new part ----
EEE
FF
```

**note** the echo statement in that for loop, if you remove the option `-e` you will see:

```
---- new part ----
AA=A\nB=BB
---- new part ----
C==CC\nDD=D
---- new part ----
EEE\nFF\n
```

take `-e` or not depends on your requirement.

Comment: This breaks if you replace `AA=A` with `AA =A` or with `AA=\\nA`

Comment: hugly step by `echo -e`, as @thatotherguy said, this won't be clean and could have a lot of *border effect*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that doesn't fumble when the data contains literal backslash sequences, spaces and other:

```
c=$(echo "AA=A"; echo "B=BB"; echo "======="; echo "C==CC"; echo "DD=D"; echo "======="; echo "EEE"; echo "FF";)
echo "more complex string"
echo "$c";
echo ;
echo "split";

c_split=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' part
do
  c_split+=( "$part" )
done < <(printf "%s" "$c" | sed -e 's/=======/\x00/g')
c_split+=( "$part" )

for i in "${c_split[@]}"
do
    echo "------ new part ------"
    echo "$i"
done
```

Note that the string is actually split on "=======" as requested, so the line feeds become part of the data (causing extra blank lines when "echo" adds its own).

Comment: EEE, FF parts lost here. also regarding the line break/line feeds, OP has given the expected output, it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Added some in the example text because of this comment:

> This breaks if you replace AA=A with AA =A or with AA=\nA – that
>   other guy

**EDIT:** I added a suggestion that isn't sensitive for some delimiter in the text. However this isn't using a "one line split" that OP was asking for, but this is how I should have done it **if** I would do it in bash, and want the result in an array.

script.sh (NEW):

```
#!/bin/bash

text=$(
  echo "AA=A"; echo "AA =A"; echo "AA=\nA"; echo "B=BB"; echo "=======";
  echo "C==CC"; echo "DD=D"; echo "======="; echo "EEE"; echo "FF";
)
echo "more complex string"
echo "$text"
echo "split now"

c_split[0]=""
current=""
del=""
ind=0

# newline
newl=$'\n'

# Save IFS (not necessary when run as sub shell)
saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS="$newl"
for row in $text; do

  if [[ $row =~ ^=+$ ]]; then
    c_split[$ind]="$current"
    ((ind++))
    current=""
    # Avoid preceding newline
    del=""
    continue
  fi

  current+="$del$row"
  del="$newl"
done

# Restore IFS
IFS="$saveIFS"

# If there is a last poor part of the text
if [[ -n $current ]]; then
  c_split[$ind]="$current"
fi

# The result is an array
for i in "${c_split[@]}"
do
    echo "---- new part ----"
    echo "$i"
done
```

script.sh (OLD, with "one line split"):
(I stool the idea with awk **from @Kent** and adjusted it a bit)

```
#!/bin/bash

c=$(
  echo "AA=A"; echo "AA =A"; echo "AA=\nA"; echo "B=BB"; echo "=======";
  echo "C==CC"; echo "DD=D"; echo "======="; echo "EEE"; echo "FF";
)
echo "more complex string"
echo "$c"
echo "split now"

# Now, this will be almost absolute secure,
# perhaps except a direct hit by lightning.
del=""
for ch in $'\1' $'\2' $'\3' $'\4' $'\5' $'\6' $'\7'; do
  if [ -z "`echo "$c" | grep "$ch"`" ]; then
    del="$ch"
    break
  fi
done

if [ -z "$del" ]; then
  echo "Sorry, all this testing but no delmiter to use..."
  exit 1
fi

IFS="$del" c_split=($(echo "$c" | awk -vRS="\n=+\n" -vORS="$del" '1'))

for i in ${c_split[@]}
do
  echo "---- new part ----"
  echo "$i"
done
```

Output:

```
[244an]$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

[244an]$ ./script.sh
more complex string
AA=A
AA =A
AA=\nA
B=BB
=======
C==CC
DD=D
=======
EEE
FF
split now
---- new part ----
AA=A
AA =A
AA=\nA
B=BB
---- new part ----
C==CC
DD=D
---- new part ----
EEE
FF
```

I'm **not** using `-e` for `echo`, to get `AA=\\nA` to not do a newline

Comment: I think you are pretty close. But now it will fail if there is a `|` in the string :P . Could you think of a way to escape it (without breaking something else)?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter what character or sequence you chose, there is always a risk that it will be in "wrong" place. If you want to keep some of the suggestions here and not rewrite it totally a test can be added to be 100% sure. Some code that chose delimiter (`|` in the above) from a list of characters, finding the first that isn't in the string. Then use that instead of always using `|`. E.g. characters to use/test: `|;,&%` etc.

Comment: Updated the answer, but sooner or later it will be better to write it better in some other language, e.g. ruby.  I finally added a better(?) alternative, but that isn't using `split` in one line (as the OP wants?).

Comment: You can use \0 as a delimiter, since this isn't allowed in string data anyways (try `var=$'foo\0bar'; echo "$var"`). This is what my suggested answer does.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but `\0` doesn't work, I think IFS needs something apart from NULL character. But I tried with `\1` instead, and it seems to work, and good to learn more about `$''` syntax, thanks. I will do a last update, but perhaps the OP doesn't have a real problem to solve, it feels more like a quiz.