# Bash: split a (multiline) string into array with a multichar delimiter

Tags: string, bash

I have the following file and call `cat myfile | ./myscript.sh`:

```
(Item)
(Values)
blabla
blabla
(StopValues)
(Item)
(Values)
hello
hello
(StopValues)
```

In my script I save the piped content from cat to a variable: `s=$(cat)`

How can I split this string to have (in context of this example) an array containing 2 variables now, one saying

```
(Item)
(Values)
blabla
blabla
(StopValues)
```

the other one saying

```
(Item)
(Values)
hello
hello
(StopValues)
```

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, since you are not mentioning anything about arrays, but the answers on this question of mine may give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630940/split-string-into-array-in-bash

Comment: @user000001 besides a general confusion what I see there is that inside his string he always has characters he wants to have removed (which can be used as delimiter, e.g. '=======
' or '/') I do not have anything that should be removed from my string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the source string is in the variable `s`, the following bash script will populate the array variable `a` as required:

```
a=()
i=0
while read -r line
do
  a[i]="${a[i]}${line}"$'\n'
  if [ "$line" == "(StopValues)" ]
  then
    let ++i
  fi
done <<< "$s"
```

Comment: one element of the array then contains only one line, e.g. "blabla", I'd rather want the "whole part" in one element just as described in the question

Comment: @RandomDisplayName Did you try running the code or you judge it without running?

Comment: I tried it, there's a twist though that might cause this to happen, I have the content in a file and pipe it to my script, I updated my question

Comment: Nevermind, it was my fault, when I echo my array like `echo ${a[0]}` its perfectly fine, but when I iterate through it with a for each loop, the item is always just one `word\n` is there a way I can get the full output just like when echoing `${a[0]}`?

Comment: @RandomDisplayName You must **quote** your variable expansions: `for x in "${a[@]}"; do ... done`

Comment: Totally missed than while checking it over and over again, thanks.

Comment: I have created a new question to do all of this file related, as reading line by line of a string takes very long (I have like 30-60k of lines per file), maybe you'll be able to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510170/bash-split-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-certain-string-and-save-new-filena