# Bash: split file into multiple files based on certain string and save new filenames into array

Tags: arrays, string, bash, file

I have a file containing the following content:

```
(Item)
(Values)
blabla
blabla
(StopValues)
(Item)
(Values)
hello
hello
(StopValues)
```

I'd like to split it into multiple files so that one file always has the content from `(Item)` to `(StopValues)` (including both of these tags). Also, as I have to further use those files and use mktemp, I'd like to save each filename in an array when creating it.

To split them I used an approach with awk:

```
  awk '/(StopValues)/{n++}{print >"out" n ".txt" }' mainfile.txt
```

First problem here, when providing 'one set' of data, I still get 2 new txt files, one containing just `(StopValues)` tag, the other one missing just this tag.

Second problem, I'd like to create files with `mktemp` instead of naming them myself and I need them in an array, how would I dynamically make new ones in the awk loop and save their name into an array?

Comment: an array you meant awk array or a bash array?

Comment: I mean a bash array

Comment: how many sections/blocks could your file have?

Comment: thats not defined, I call my script like this `cat *.txt | ./script` and all the content from cat is written in one file. When I pipe the cat of all files like that, would there be a possibility to see which content came from which "cat(ed) file", respectively split it and directly get it as array? Because if thats possible all I try to do is not needed anymore

Comment: ok, all clear, posted my answer.

Comment: `man csplit`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the command:

```
arr=($(awk 'BEGIN{cmd="mktemp -u"; cmd|getline tmp}
{print > tmp}/\(StopValues/{a[++i]=tmp;close(cmd);close(tmp); cmd|getline tmp;}END{for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)print a[i]; }' inputFile ))
```

The awk part:

```
awk 'BEGIN{cmd="mktemp -u"; cmd|getline tmp}
     {print > tmp}
     /\(StopValues/{a[++i]=tmp
                    close(cmd)
                    close(tmp)
                    cmd|getline tmp} 
    END{for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)print a[i]; }' inputFile
```

With this `inputFile (f)`: (I added the third block)

```
kent$  cat f
(Item)
(Values)
blabla
blabla
(StopValues)
(Item)
(Values)
hello
hello
(StopValues)
(Item)
(Values)
hello
hello
(StopValues)
```

The awk will output:

```
#The filenames can be different.
/tmp/tmp.DRaLMsXROR
/tmp/tmp.yUL6GO4xtv
/tmp/tmp.Kb0UxsHVno
```

So you can see the output have 3 temp files. Each file contains a block of input file.

The outputs have the temp file names, which we put in the bash array declaration, thus we have them in array. So put all together, we do a test:(here I just check the first block/tempfile):

```
kent$  arr=($(awk 'BEGIN{cmd="mktemp -u"; cmd|getline tmp}                                                                                                                  
    {print > tmp}/\(StopValues/{a[++i]=tmp;close(cmd);close(tmp); cmd|getline tmp;}END{for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)print a[i]; }' f ))

kent$  echo ${arr[*]}                                                                                                                                                       
/tmp/tmp.fcf7ac0eVl /tmp/tmp.Rjru5psFQB /tmp/tmp.ldaBWCucNg

kent$  echo ${arr[1]}
/tmp/tmp.fcf7ac0eVl

kent$  cat $(echo ${arr[1]})                              
(Item)
(Values)
blabla
blabla
(StopValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Try:

```
awk '/(Item)/{A=1;count++} A{VAL=VAL?VAL ORS $0:$0} /(StopValues)/{A="";print VAL > "out" count ".txt";VAL=""}'   Input_file
```

Will create 2 files out2.txt and out1.txt.

**EDIT:** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '/(Item)/{
                A=1;
                count++
             }
    A        {
                VAL=VAL?VAL ORS $0:$0
             }
    /(StopValues)/{
                        A="";
                        print VAL > "out" count ".txt";
                        VAL=""
                  }
    '    Input_file
```